# Setting FontFamily of TextBox applicationwide

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface, textbox, font-family

I have a big project at hand which involves a large amount of views and usercontrols. Additionaly, I want to set the FontFamily of every element to a certain font.

This works with most of the usercontrols like textBlocks, buttons and labels. Sadly this does not hold for textBoxes. They remain unchanged.

Before I create the whole GUI, I am overriding most of the metadata for elements containing text:

```
TextElement.FontFamilyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TextElement), 
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new FontFamily("Calibri")));
TextBlock.FontFamilyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TextBlock), 
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new FontFamily("Calibri")));
```

After a bit of searching, I found this article using the same method: [http://blog.davidpadbury.com/](http://blog.davidpadbury.com/2008/08/30/change-the-default-font-of-a-wpf-application/)

It clearly states at the end:

"In the above image you’ll see that we’ve successfully change the font on the text blocks, labels and buttons. Unfortunately the font inside the TextBox remains unchanged, this is due to it receiving it’s FontFamily property from it’s base class Control. Control adds itself as an Owner of the TextElement FontFamilyProperty but specifies it’s own metadata which we are then unable to override."

It also suggests to create a control template, which then sets the fontFamily. Is there another way? I want to set the fontFamily programmatically at the start without using XAML or creating a controlTemplate and using it as a base template for every textBox.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a `Style` *without the `x:Key` property* and it will apply to all controls of that type:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri" />
</Style>
```

Alternatively, you can simply set this on the `MainWindow` definition which will affect most elements:

```
<Window TextElement.FontFamily="Calibri" ...>
    ...
</Window>
```

Ahhh... I've just noticed your condition of *not* using xaml... sorry, I should have looked closer the first time.

---

UPDATE >>>

After a little research, it seems that you can do this in code like this:

```
Style style = new Style(typeof(TextBlock));
Setter setter = new Setter();
setter.Property = TextElement.FontFamilyProperty;
setter.Value = new FontFamily("Calibri");
style.Setters.Add(setter);
Resources.Add(typeof(TextBlock), style);
```

Unfortunately, you'd have to do other `Style`s for other types of controls too.

---

UPDATE 2 >>>

I just thought of something... that previous example just set the `Style` into the local `Resources` section which would be out of scope for your other modules. You could try setting the `Style` to the `Application.Resources` section which has global scope. Try replacing the last line of the code example above to this:

```
App.Current.Resources.Add(typeof(TextBlock), style);
```

Comment: Sadly, neither of both is working for me. I tried it that way before. The textboxes are just using the systemStandard font. Using TextBox as the targetType does indeed work, but is not what I am looking for. I want to change the font programmatically according to the system Language

Comment: That's strange because I regularly use this XAML which works fine for me and I tested this C# code which also worked fine for me.

Comment: As i said, the project is quite large and is using Prism with lots of modules. Maybe your code is just right and the problem is lying somewhere else burried inside one of the modules. Your solution sounds right to me too. But I cant figure out why the FontFamily is changed here. The whole project does not contain any change of the FontFamily except of mine. Thank you anyway, you helped to narrow down the error sources. I will have to keep on looking or find a workaroung.

Comment: Thank you very much, your newest update did change some of the textboxes.Sadly some did not. But this seems to be related to Prism and the structure of the project.